# How to disable a shopt option in Bash?

Tags: bash, shopt

How to disable a `shopt` option, for example `extglob`?

I have this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: There is an option `-u` to disable it. But the problem, is since you have it in `.bashrc`, the setting is enabled in every login shell. You need to do `shopt -u extglob` every time you want to disable it

Comment: `shopt` is a bash builtin command. See `help shopt`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `-u` option:

```
shopt -u extglob
```

- `-s` is for setting and `-u` is for unsetting.

From `help shopt` (or `shopt --help` as well on BSD systems):

```
Options:
  -o    restrict OPTNAMEs to those defined for use with `set -o'
  -p    print each shell option with an indication of its status
  -q    suppress output
  -s    enable (set) each OPTNAME
  -u    disable (unset) each OPTNAME
```

---

To see how to do shopt in a clean way, see this:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/shopt.sh